# How can I use HTML5 Request.Form to get list values?

Tags: html, request.form

I'm new to HTML5. I have a list structure on the form. This is the generated HTML:

```
<div id="acctCode1">
<input class="entity" id="Entities1_0_" name="Entities1[0]" type="text" value="788" /><br/>
<input class="entity" id="Entities1_1_" name="Entities1[1]" type="text" value="Q83" /><br/>
<input class="entity" id="Entities1_2_" name="Entities1[2]" type="text" value="" /><br/>
</div>
```

When the Form is posted, I need to get the entity values into a list.  Here's my code (I've kept it simple so it's easy to understand):

```
var ent1 = new string[20];
for (int i = 0; i < ent1.Count; i++)
{
    var entKey = "Entities1[" + i.ToString() + "]";
    var acct = Request.Form[entKey];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acct))
    {
        ent1[i] = acct;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The best I can say about this code is that it works. I've looked through the Request and the Form objects and I can't find a better way to get the values.

Isn't there a less kludgey way to pick up all the values from the Entities1 list?

Comment: Before trying to answer your question -- what are you trying to do with the "Entities" list?  Are you validating form input values?  Can you just use more specific input types (`email`, `tel`, `url`, etc) and the `required` attribute?

Comment: The "entities" are codes for business entities that the user can see on-line. They are just strings that we list on the form. If the user has edit access, they can add new ones.